# onclick() is not working with parameter for multiple time, value printing first time then its coming undefine

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, single-page-application

[image]

In a single page application from the first image in that on click arrow we are navigating in to the next section with taking the name parameter eg. in which row we are clicking we are taking the same name. And we are able to get the name in summary tab section. After that we navigating to objective tab and we are getting the name by the seted id . But when we are going back to summary page at that time its becoming undefined. At that time the name which we are selected is not appearing.

`<a onClick="mySummary( \'' + myName + '\')"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>`

`function mySummary(myName) { //value fetching }`

```
<a onclick="mySummary(myName)">Summary</a>
```

Note: Whole application is written in one html page. We are using show view concept to go one and another section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will be helpful. Below in anchor tag data-val value must be set dynamically

```
<a class="aclass" data-val="myName" ><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.aclass', function () {
   myName = $(this).attr("data-val");
   //Here will be your code of mySummary function

});
</script>
```

Comment: This code is not working but in my previous code if i pass the parameter in mySummary(myName) and in other methods too that time its taking the last element of the row. eg: Test 1 from the first image.